# Return FALSE for duplicated NA values when using the function duplicated()

Tags: r, comparison, duplicates, missing-data

just wondering why duplicated behaves the way it does with NAs:

```
> duplicated(c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,2))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

where in fact

```
> NA == NA
[1] NA
```

is there a way to achieve that duplicated marks NAs as false, like this?

```
> duplicated(c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,2))
[1] FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `duplicated` marks the second (and third, and fourth, etc.) occurrences as duplicated, but not the first. You can use `is.na()` to do what you ask.

Comment: thanks. The main question is why it makes sense to mark NAs as duplicates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use the argument `incomparables` for the function `duplicated` like this :

```
> duplicated(c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,2))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> duplicated(c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,2),incomparables=NA)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

It determines the values that cannot be compared (in this case `NA`) and returns `FALSE` for those values. See also `?duplicated`